# Create new column which is the aggregation of a few other columns who meet certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a pandas dataframe (population) and I want to add a new column to it. The new column should be - of course for every index/row - the sum of all (and only) the columns who has the substring 'ussr' in their names.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate this column running:

```
df['MySum'] = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('ussr', case=False)]].sum(axis=1)
```

Details:

- `df.columns.str.contains('ussr', ...)` - creates a list of **boolean** -
  whether particular column contains *ussr* string.
- `case=False` - case insensitive (if you need).
- `df.columns[...]` - creates a list of **columns** containing this string.
- `df[...]` - retrieves content of these columns.
- `sum(axis=1)` - generates sums for these columns, for each row.
- `df['MySum'] = ...` - saves the result under the given column.

You may change the target column name to whatever you wish, but avoid
placing *ussr* in its name. Otherwise, when you run the above instruction
again, its value will also be taken as one of source elements.

Comment: Thanks for a helping and educating answer!